# React state in different component on different page route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have been able to setState on a specific component called `SubmitProject` which lives at a specific route `/submit`. Now I also have a route `/portfolio` that has a component called `Portfolio` I am wondering how do I get the state from `SubmitProject` to be the same on `Portfolio` Can you only share state with Components that are nested within each other. What I am ultimately trying to do is use a form to submit text to state on the `/submit` route and then have that same state data update in the `/portfolio` route.

I could be approaching the design wrong, Should everything maybe be in APP Component and I do the Routing different, I am very new to React, so I defintely need guidance on how to setup my project.

Ok Thanks ahead of time.

Here is my relevant code

**`src/components/SubmitProject.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioForm from './PortfolioForm';

class SubmitProject extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sections:{}
    };
    addSection = section =>{
        const sections = {...this.state.sections};
        sections[`section${Date.now()}`] = section;
        this.setState({
            sections: sections
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Submit Project</h1>
                <h2>Enter Project Data</h2>
                <PortfolioForm addSection={this.addSection} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default SubmitProject;
```

**`src/components/PortfolioForm.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import FormAdd from './FormAdd';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Submit Form</h1>
                <FormAdd addSection={this.props.addSection}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

**`src/components/FormAdd.js`**

```
import React from 'react';

class FormAdd extends React.Component {
    nameRef = React.createRef();

    createSection = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const section = {
            name: this.nameRef.current.value
        };
        this.props.addSection(section);
    };  
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <form onSubmit={this.createSection}>
                    <input type="text" ref={this.nameRef} name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                    <button type="submit">+ Add Section</button>
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default FormAdd;
```

**`src/components/Router.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
import SubmitProject from './SubmitProject';
import App from './App';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio}/>
            <Route exact path="/submit" component={SubmitProject}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

**`src/Portfolio.js`**

```
import React from 'react';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    //CAN I GET STATE FROM SubmitProject.js FILE IN HERE?
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Portfolio Page</h1>
                <h2>List of projects</h2>        
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: An externalised state management solution like redux/mobx, or react's context api would solve this problem - are you familiar with these?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React 16, then you could resolve this by using the Context API. This would involve making the following adjustments to your code:

```
// PortfolioContext.jsx
// Define a PortfolioContext component with initial shared 'sections' state
export default const PortfolioContext = React.createContext(
  sections : {}
);
```

Then update your SubmitProject component to use the `PortfolioContext` component to update the shared `sections` state:

```
// SubmitProject.jsx
// Use the ProtfolioContext component in your SubmitProject component to update
// the shared for use in the Portfolio component
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioForm from './PortfolioForm';
import PortfolioContext from './PortfolioContext';

class SubmitProject extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
             sections:{}
        };
    }

    addSection = section =>{
        const sections = {...this.state.sections};
        sections[`section${Date.now()}`] = section;
        this.setState({
            sections: sections
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            { /* Inject the local sections state into provider */ }
            <PortfolioContext.Provider value={this.state.sections}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h1>Submit Project</h1>
                    <h2>Enter Project Data</h2>
                    <PortfolioForm addSection={this.addSection} />
                </React.Fragment>
            </PortfolioContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default SubmitProject;
```

And also update your Portfolio component to use the `PortfolioContext` component to get the shared state:

```
// Portfolio.jsx
import React from 'react';
import PortfolioContext from './PortfolioContext';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
    //CAN I GET STATE FROM SubmitProject.js FILE IN HERE?
    render() {
        return(
            { /* Use the PortfolioContext.Consumer to access sections state */}
            <PortfolioContext.Consumer>
            {
                sections => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <h1>Portfolio Page</h1>
                        <h2>List of projects</h2>        
                        { /* here is the shared state - access and render section data as needed. This is just a demonstration to show how the data can be rendered in some way */ }
                        { Object.values(sections || {}).map(section => (<p>JSON.stringify(section)</p>) )}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            }
             </PortfolioContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you think this is a good idea, or should I rewrite my code so everything is inside App and I can pass down state via props. In the react docs when referring to context api it says `Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.`

Comment: That's true - it really depends on your project specifics. If you can achieve the same result via state pass down by props then that might be the better approach. If you have a deep component hierarchy then passing props from the top to bottom of the hierarchy may be difficult to maintain, in which case the context based approach might be better.

Comment: So my editor underlines the `:` in the `sections: {},` Is there something wrong with that code?

Comment: This is how `createContext` is shown in the react docs `const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');` should I be putting the `'sections:{}',` in quotes like so.

Comment: I think it is because you were missing `{}` like so `export const PortfolioContext = React.createContext({
    sections : {}
});`

Comment: I also get a `ThemeContext` is not defined error for Portfolio.js and it is missing a closing tag, also If I delete it all together I get this error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {sections})`

Comment: Hey, I am still getting the same error, you can see it in more details here https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/130G2a3N0u401J3Z3z2H/Image%202018-10-05%20at%208.00.34%20PM.png?v=853b1b07

Comment: Yes, this is because you need to render out your `sections` in the way that you intend to show them to the user in the UI. I'm not exactly sure what each section object contains, or how you intend to render the sections - I've updated the answer to show how you can render a list of section values from your `sections` object.

Comment: I get the following error in the console `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` and the code above just outputs this as a string `JSON.stringify(section)`

Comment: That's just a warning - that particular code is not intended as final code, and is just intended to show you how you can access that shared `sections` state from the `Portfolio` component (see my comments that are in line to that part of the code)